# PowerPivot YTD with Missing Data

Tags: powerpivot

Problem with computation of YTD if Data on a particular period is not existing

[image]

Using formula

**YTDUnits =CALCULATE(SUM(Data[TYUnits]),DATESYTD(Data[FullDate]),ALL(Data[Month])))**

Data came from a csv file, and am only using 1 table in the data model.

In this example, Month 2 should have a value of 6 on TransactionType c.
Is there a way to fill this?

In the data model, no record exists for TransactionType c Month 2

[image]

Comment: You need to add a Calendar table to your data model, and use its dates instead of data dates.

Comment: I've tried adding Calendar table and changed my formula to this =CALCULATE(SUM(Data[TYUnits]),DATESYTD('Calendar'[FullDate]),ALL('Calendar'[Month]))) but it still did not work

Comment: Try it without ALL('Calendar'[Month]). Also, make sure you have proper dates in your pivot table (I would put Year-Month)

Comment: Tried the ALL('Calendar'[Month]), and it just makes wrong values for the YTD, and it still doesn't work for the blanks

Comment: Month values in your pivot - where are they from? From data table, or from Calendar table?

Comment: From Data. Also tried from calendar table, same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually typed in your data sample, and built the data model:

[image]

Put Year-Month from the calendar table on the pivot, and added this DAX measure:

```
YTDUnits = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[TYUnits]), DATESYTD('Calendar'[Date]))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have already reproduced it exactly, so my answer should work.

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks for the help